# RxBinding DatePicker and TimePicker

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-binding

I'm trying to get the values from DatePicker, but I've no idea how could I manage it.

My layout contains a DatePicker element, and I'm using kotlin.

Same problem with TimePicker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for [Márton Soós](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10230467/m%C3%A1rton-so%C3%B3s)

This helper class does the magic for both DatePicker and TimePicker:

```
data class DatePickerChangeEvent(
        val view: View,
        val year: Int = 0,
        val monthOfYear: Int = 0,
        val dayOfMonth: Int = 0
)

data class TimePickerChangeEvent(
        val view: View,
        val hour: Int,
        val minute: Int
)

 class DatePickerObservable(val view: DatePicker, val year: Int, val monthOfYear: Int, val dayOfMonth: Int)
    : io.reactivex.Observable<DatePickerChangeEvent>() {

    override fun subscribeActual(observer: Observer<in DatePickerChangeEvent>) {
        val listener = DateChangeListener(view, observer)
        observer.onSubscribe(listener)
        view.init(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth, listener)
    }

    class DateChangeListener(private val dp: DatePicker, private val obs: io.reactivex.Observer<in DatePickerChangeEvent>)
        : DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener, MainThreadDisposable() {

        override fun onDateChanged(p0: DatePicker, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
            obs.onNext(DatePickerChangeEvent(dp, p1, p2, p3))
        }

        override fun onDispose() {
        }
    }
}

class TimePickerObservable(val view: TimePicker)
    : io.reactivex.Observable<TimePickerChangeEvent>() {

    override fun subscribeActual(observer: Observer<in TimePickerChangeEvent>) {
        val listener = TimeChangeListener(view, observer)
        observer.onSubscribe(listener)
        view.setOnTimeChangedListener(listener)
    }

    class TimeChangeListener(private val tp: TimePicker, private val obs: io.reactivex.Observer<in TimePickerChangeEvent>)
        : TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener, MainThreadDisposable() {

        override fun onTimeChanged(p0: TimePicker, p1: Int, p2: Int) {
            obs.onNext(TimePickerChangeEvent(p0, p1, p2))
        }

        override fun onDispose() {
            tp.setOnTimeChangedListener { timePicker, i, i2 -> }
        }
    }
}

@Suppress("NOTHING_TO_INLINE")
inline fun DatePicker.dateChange(year: Int, monthOfYear: Int, dayOfMonth: Int): DatePickerObservable =
        DatePickerObservable(this, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth)

@Suppress("NOTHING_TO_INLINE")
inline fun TimePicker.timeChange(): TimePickerObservable =
        TimePickerObservable(this)
```

Than you can call it:

```
 datePicker.dateChange(2018,9,15)
                .subscribe{
                    Log.d("RxDate", it.toString())
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more specific? Do you want to show DatePicker and TimePicker to user and get the user selected value? In that case, you can try like this.
For DatePicker,

```
val mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance()
val mYear = mCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)
val mMonth = mCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)
val mDay = mCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)

val dpd = DatePickerDialog(
      this, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { _, thisYear, thisMonth, thisDay ->

    mYear = thisYear
    mMonth = thisMonth
    mDay = thisDay

    tDate.text = mDay.toString() + "/" + (mMonth + 1).toString() +
        "/" + mYear.toString()

  }, mYear, mMonth, mDay
  )
  dpd.show()
```

For TimePicker,

```
TimePickerDialog(this, TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener { _, hourOfDay, minute ->
tvHour.text = Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay
tvMinute.text = Calendar.MINUTE, minute
}, mCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), mCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE), false).show()
```

Comment: My XML file contains a <DatePicker.../> element. In RxBinding I usually use something like this: 
RxView.cliks(button)
.map{it}
.subscribe{navigateToOtherFragment}

I looking for something like this.

Comment: Sorry guy, I just misunderstood the question. You are asking about RxBinding pickers.